# How to remove uiviewanimation block on touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation

I am calling a function [self moveFishLeft] from viewDidLoad and the objects are animating properly but when I am trying to remove animation on touchesBeganWithEvent the animation still remains. So how do I remove all the left and right function animation on screen touch.

```
- (void)moveFishLeft {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:6.0f   
                          delay:0.0f   
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent  
                     animations:^{  
                         [optionView1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 480, 130, 110)];  
                         [optionView2 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 600, 130, 110)];   
                         [optionView3 setFrame:CGRectMake(130, 530, 130, 110)];  
                         [optionView4 setFrame:CGRectMake(130, 670, 130, 110)];  
                         [optionView5 setFrame:CGRectMake(130, 780, 130, 110)];  
                         [optionView6 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 720, 130, 110)];
                                    }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                         [optionView1.layer removeAllAnimations];
                         [optionView2.layer removeAllAnimations];
                         [optionView3.layer removeAllAnimations];
                         [optionView4.layer removeAllAnimations];
                         [optionView5.layer removeAllAnimations];
                         [optionView6.layer removeAllAnimations];

                         [optionImage1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fish1_right"]];
                         [optionImage2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fish1_right"]];
                         [optionImage3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fish1_right"]];
                         [optionImage4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fish1_right"]];
                         [optionImage5 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fish1_right"]];
                         [optionImage6 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fish1_right"]];

                         [self moveFishRight];
                     }];
}


- (void)moveFishRight {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:6.0f      
                          delay:0.0f        
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent       
                     animations:^{     
                         [optionView1 setFrame:CGRectMake(530, 480, 130, 110)];     
                         [optionView2 setFrame:CGRectMake(530, 600, 130, 110)];      
                         [optionView3 setFrame:CGRectMake(638, 530, 130, 110)];      
                         [optionView4 setFrame:CGRectMake(638, 670, 130, 110)];      
                         [optionView5 setFrame:CGRectMake(638, 780, 130, 110)];        
                         [optionView6 setFrame:CGRectMake(530, 720, 130, 110)];      
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                         [optionView1.layer removeAllAnimations];
                         [optionView2.layer removeAllAnimations];
                         [optionView3.layer removeAllAnimations];
                         [optionView4.layer removeAllAnimations];
                         [optionView5.layer removeAllAnimations];
                         [optionView6.layer removeAllAnimations];

                         [optionImage1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fish1"]];
                         [optionImage2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fish1"]];
                         [optionImage3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fish1"]];
                         [optionImage4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fish1"]];
                         [optionImage5 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fish1"]];
                         [optionImage6 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fish1"]];

                         [self moveFishLeft];
                     }];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    [optionView1.layer removeAllAnimations];
    [optionView2.layer removeAllAnimations];
    [optionView3.layer removeAllAnimations];
    [optionView4.layer removeAllAnimations];
    [optionView5.layer removeAllAnimations];
    [optionView6.layer removeAllAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below code:- 
`[self.view.layer removeAllAnimations];`  use this may be it's useful.

Comment: When I click on the screen, the animation restarts from either frame.origin.x = 0 or frame.origin.x = 530 alternatively.

Comment: Add this line code when you want to stop animation [UIView commitAnimations];

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to wrap all the "removeAllAnimations" in a CATransaction:

(Requires QuartzCore import)

```
[CATransaction begin];
[optionView1.layer removeAllAnimations];
[optionView2.layer removeAllAnimations];
[optionView3.layer removeAllAnimations];
[optionView4.layer removeAllAnimations];
[optionView5.layer removeAllAnimations];
[optionView6.layer removeAllAnimations];
[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: I guess its still not working. When I click on the screen, the animation restarts from either frame.origin.x = 0 or frame.origin.x = 530 alternatively.